# Python: list comprehension based on previous value?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Say I want to create a list *using list comprehension* like:

```
l = [100., 50., 25., 12.5, ..., a_n]
```

…i.e., start with some number and generate the n "halves" from that in the same list. I might either be missing some straightforward pythonic way of doing that, or I'll simply have to rely on a good ol' for-loop. Can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: I guess it's possible to use a list comp for this but it seems like a good use case for a generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
start = 2500.0
n = 50
halves = [start / 2.0**i for i in range(n)]
```

equal to this:

```
[start * 2.0**(-i) for i in range(n)]
```

probably less efficient in contrast to @DeepSpace's answer but a one-liner

Comment: I think OP wanted to generate an `n` length list.

Comment: Ok, I added a length variable

Answer (score 5):

Define a generator, and use it in the list comprehension:

```
def halve(n):
    while n >= 1:
        yield n
        n /= 2

print([_ for _ in halve(100)])
>> [100, 50.0, 25.0, 12.5, 6.25, 3.125, 1.5625]
```

Or simply convert it to a list:

```
print(list(halve(100)))
>> [100, 50.0, 25.0, 12.5, 6.25, 3.125, 1.5625]
```

**EDIT** In case @R Nar's comment is correct:

```
def halve(start, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield start
        start /= 2

print(list(halve(100, 3)))
>> [100, 50.0, 25.0]

print(list(halve(100, 4)))
>> [100, 50.0, 25.0, 12.5]
```

Comment: I think OP meant `n` number of halves, so if `n = 100`, it should return a list of 100 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works with int but not floats.

```
[100>>i for i in range(10)]
```

this returns:

```
[100, 50, 25, 12, 6, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This _is_ some nice bit-level hacking :)

Comment: @Finwood, it would be if it worked, it does do at all what the OP wants.

Comment: Well, let's call it a rough estimation. But I like the approach :-)

Comment: yeah would be nice if it worked :) but why voting down ?

Comment: It works fine until the lowest list integer <= 2, the rest will then be zeros. Not too bad actually.

Comment: @gustafbstrom, how does it work fine? Have you actually read the question or looked at the expected output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's not flawless. What I meant is that under the constraint that you'll allow integer truncation and do not choose a too low starting number for a too long list, it may be a useful approximation sometimes.

Comment: User specifically had float values in their question, but this is otherwise very creative. I like it

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Python 3.8.5):

```
from itertools import accumulate 

n=5
result = list(accumulate(range(n), lambda acc, val: acc/2, initial=100))
print(result)
```